# How can I pass a file from a source repo to an agent Dockerfile within a Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have a pipeline setup to successfully checkout a git repo, pull in a Jenkinsfile, then use a Dockerfile contained in said repo to create a pipeline agent.

My issue is that I am trying to run a `pip install -r requirements.txt` inside the Dockerfile using a `requirements.txt` file also found in the repo, but I haven't been able to find a way to pass it to the Dockerfile.

I understand I can run the pip install in the Jenkinsfile during subsequent stages, but I'd prefer to keep the Dockerfile doing as much heavy lifting as possible.

Jenkinsfile:

```
* Requires the Docker Pipeline plugin */
pipeline {
    agent {
        dockerfile {
            dir 'ci/unit_test'
        }
    }
}
```

I've already tried using `checkout scm` during the `agent` stage but kept erroring out.

Answer (score 0):

What is have understood from your question is that you need to install the requirement.txt content in your images.

So you need to use one of the Dockerfile directives which is COPY and ADD

Difference between COPY and ADD:-

**COPY** only supports the basic copying of local files into the container, while
**ADD** has some features (like local-only tar extraction and remote URL support)

**COPY** "path of your source file" "path in the image"
and you can also use

**ADD** "path of your source file" "path in the image"

**Note:** *The path must correspond to where your Dockerfile resides.*

Let me know if I have understood the requirement wrong.